# Check in a lot of files in sharepoint online (Document center)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Here it's my problem :
I started to move a lot of files in a document center, but yesterday I learned that users cannot see them, but permissions we're all right. I checked, and finally found that files were on checkout mode, meaning that they needed an approval. So I have to check all the files and select "Check in".

As it is a lot of files, I want to know if it is possible to create a powershell script to do it, and if it's possible, can you give me some help to create it.

I'm totally a noob in powershell, so I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks for reading and for your help. :)

Edit : I tried Sharepoint Designer, and it didn't worked. I tried to create a view on the website to see files without the folders, but the selection is limited to 100 objects at once. I've got like 67000 elements, so I can't use this method.

The only solution is to create a powershell script.

I found this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.checkin.aspx

This might be the solution I'm looking for.

The question I got now is : Will this API work with Sharepoint Online ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this option is available in SPO, but this is how I do it on-prem. Within Site Settings, go to 'Content and Structure'. Navigate into the document library you'd like to work with, and then select all documents within it. Click 'Actions' and 'Check In'.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your answer, I tried it, but you cannot check in files directly on folders with this view. A colleague told me that you can do it with Sharepoint Designer, I'm going to give it a try. :)